# mocking an error message in Rspec when method calls .backtrace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

i have a method that logs errors.  It was taking an error message as a parameter but now it takes an entire error and calls .backtrace on it.  The method is below:

```
def log_error(error)
    puts error.backtrace
    puts "RECONCILE_TAX_RATES [#{Time.now}] ERROR [#{error.message}]"
  end
```

I am trying to test it and I cant figure out the syntax for the test.  WHat I had before is:

```
it 'logs errors' do
    time = "Tue, 16 Sep 2014 20:18:19 UTC +00:00"
    Timecop.freeze(time) do
      tax_reconciler = TaxReconciler.new
      error_message = "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that."
      expected = "RECONCILE_TAX_RATES [2014-09-16 20:18:19 UTC] ERROR [I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.]"

      STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with(expected)
      tax_reconciler.log_error(error_message)
    end
  end
```

I have tried various combinations from the rSpec docs but I keep getting tripped up on the .backtrace method.  How can I mock this error message so that .backtrace doesn't blow up?  Thanks in advance for your help and let me know if I need to give anymore information.

Edit:  For anyone with a similar problem the solution I used was:

```
 it 'logs errors' do
    time = "Tue, 16 Sep 2014 20:18:19 UTC +00:00"
    Timecop.freeze(time) do
      expected = "RECONCILE_TAX_RATES [2014-09-16 20:18:19 UTC] ERROR [I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.]"
      tax_reconciler = TaxReconciler.new
      begin
        raise "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that."
      rescue => error_message
        STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with(expected)
        STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with(error_message.backtrace)
        tax_reconciler.log_error(error_message)
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
describe '#log_error' do
  let(:time)    { 'Tue, 16 Sep 2014 20:18:19 UTC +00:00' }
  let(:message) { 'The message' }
  let(:error)   { double(:message => message, :backtrace => []) }
  let(:line)    { 'RECONCILE_TAX_RATES [2014-09-16 20:18:19 UTC] ERROR [The message]' }

  subject(:tax_reconciler) { TaxReconciler.new }

  before { allow(STDOUT).to receive(:puts) }

  it 'logs errors' do
    Timecop.freeze(time) do
      tax_reconciler.log_error(error)
      expect(STDOUT).to have_receive(:puts).with(line)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: when I try this way I get:    undefined method `allow' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_4:0x007fa0048ad238>

Comment: The `allow` method comes with the `rspec-mocks` gem. See: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks

Comment: I have rspec-mocks in the application but an older version(2.12.2.).  Is there a syntax that is supported by this older version?  The application is pretty big so I don't want to update and break all of the other tests if 3.1.1 is not backwards compatible.